# Yii2: Kartik GridView Excel export

Tags: excel, gridview, yii2

Using the great [Yii2 extension GridView from Kartik](https://demos.krajee.com/grid) I need to export data in Excel format.

I have tons of data (30.000+ rows) and enabled pagination in the view.

But when exporting to Excel I need to export all rows at once. Is there a configuration option for a full export of all rows and not just the displayed rows in a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have to expand the table before exporting the data.

In your case - a lot of rows - it would be better to use the [yii2-export-menu](https://demos.krajee.com/export-demo) extension.

Source: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/423